# How do I horizontally expand a box to reveal hidden text when hovered over

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm still learning css, so I'm experimenting a little bit with animations and such. Right now I'm trying to make a "skill bar" that would list, in this case, programming languages and expand horizontally to reveal a percentage when the box was hovered over. I have the list right now and it expands the way I want it to, however I'm not entirely sure how to actually create the hidden text. I'm certain there's a much better way to do it, but the way that I was trying to do was use flex-box to align the columns and have the boxes expand over the percentages to reveal them like that. But I didn't consider the fact that the expanding flexbox would just push the other column away from it.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
                        <div class="pointer-container">

                            <div class="pointer">Proficient Languages</div>

                            <div class="skills">
                                <div class="banner-container">
                                    <div class="banner">HTML</div>
                                    <div class="banner">CSS</div>
                                    <div class="banner">PHP</div>
                                    <div class="banner">JavaScript</div>
                                    <div class="banner">React Native</div>
                                    <div class="banner">Java</div>
                                    <div class="banner">C#</div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="levels">
                                    <p>%</p>
                                    <p>%</p>
                                    <p>%</p>
                                    <p>%</p>
                                    <p>%</p>
                                    <p>%</p>
                                    <p>%</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                       </div>
```

And my css:

```
.pointer-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.skills{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

/*shape banners and style text inside*/
banner{
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: #00a6ff;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: width 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.banner:hover {
    width: 400px;
}

/*give shape to the pointer header*/
.pointer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: #00a6ff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10;
}

.pointer:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.pointer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid #00a6ff;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

sorry if it's a little messy, but any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rearrange your HTML to something like this:

```
<div class="skills">
  <div class="banner-container">
    <div class="banner">
      <span class="skill">HTML</span><span class="level">%</span>
      <span class="skill">CSS</span><span class="level">%</span>
      <!-- etc -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then your CSS could be:

```
.level {
 display: none;
}

.banner:hover .level {
  display: inline-block; /* or whatever */
}
```

It also makes sense semantically, right? Your skill's name and how proficient you are with it kind of belong together.

Comment: I totally forgot about span class! Thank you, this helped me figure out how to fix it!